# Use of malloc in C programing

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, malloc

What is the difference between following snippets of code?

```
int main()
{
 int *p;
 p= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

and

```
int main()
{ 
 int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: The first is an assignment to `p`. The second is an initialization of `p`. The end result is the same, but there is a semantic difference.

Comment: You did understand that this question is unrelated to `malloc`.

Comment: You can write `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p))` instead, to avoid using `sizeof(int)` and typecast `(int*)`.However, in response to your actual question, there is no significant difference between those two statements. You can use either.

Comment: @RoadRunner Since `sizeof` is not a function, the parentheses can be dropped whenever the argument is not a type name. So, it can be `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`.

Comment: Yeah that is true @unwind. Probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

- The first snippet is two-step, defining a pointer and then, [**assigning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) a *valid<sup>**</sup>* value to the pointer.
- The second snippet declares and [**initializes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) the pointer via the call to `malloc()` in a single step.

In effect, end results of both the snippet are same. It's more about coding standard guidelines for which one to use.

One suggestion though, in case using the first style, consider initializing the pointer to `NULL` to prevent accidental use of the pointer *before* the assignment.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

---

** [Note]: provided, `malloc()` success.

Comment: I don't get this: _in case using the first style, consider initializing the pointer to NULL to prevent accidental use of the pointer before the assignment_, OP is not using `realloc` (there is no problem using `malloc` with an uninitialized pointer).

Comment: @KeineLust: This is a general coding guideline. Usually programs involving pointers and malloc() are more complex and mistakes may arise.

Comment: @KeineLust just to clear up, by saying _use_, i meant _defererence_. Any better?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, no, is fine, I've misreaded the answer, sorry :(